# Making a custom titlebar with glfw

Tags: c++, winapi, glfw

So like I said in the title, I want to have a custom title bar like for example chrome, discord, steam, etc...

Right now , im using the glfw native access to completely disable the title bar so that I can draw my own with opengl. Now I have found a solution which kinda works but there is an issue.

At the top of the window where there was a titlebar before, there is a very thin white frame which in my testing does not have any purpose and just exists for no reason. It's really annoying and I cant find a way to remove it.

The code I used to disable the titlebar:

```
void disableTitlebar(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    HWND hWnd = glfwGetWin32Window(window);

    // Remove the title bar
    LONG_PTR lStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
    lStyle &= ~WS_CAPTION;
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);

    // Set the window shape and rounded corners
    DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY policy = DWMNCRP_ENABLED;
    DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY, &policy, sizeof(policy));

    // Extend the frame into the client area
    MARGINS margins = { -1 };
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &margins);

    // Adjust the window size to remove the thin frame at the top
    RECT windowRect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &windowRect);
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, 0, 0, windowRect.right - windowRect.left, windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE);
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the issue im talking about: [imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd9CU.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Tried tweaking the margins value and looked online but I couldn't find a solution that uses glfw.
Even asked chat gpt, no help from him either.

Answer (score 1):

Hey so I figured a solution after a lot of researching. I dont now if it's the best to do what I want but it works and I didnt notice and performance drop or anything like that.

here is the code for anyone in the same situation as me.

```
WNDPROC original_proc;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        {
            // Remove the window's standard sizing border
            if (wParam == TRUE && lParam != NULL)
            {
                NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* pParams = reinterpret_cast<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*>(lParam);
                pParams->rgrc[0].top += 1;
                pParams->rgrc[0].right -= 2;
                pParams->rgrc[0].bottom -= 2;
                pParams->rgrc[0].left += 2;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_NCPAINT:
        {
            // Prevent the non-client area from being painted
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_NCHITTEST:
        {
            // Expand the hit test area for resizing
            const int borderWidth = 8; // Adjust this value to control the hit test area size

            POINTS mousePos = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);
            POINT clientMousePos = { mousePos.x, mousePos.y };
            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &clientMousePos);

            RECT windowRect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &windowRect);

            if (clientMousePos.y >= windowRect.bottom - borderWidth)
            {
                if (clientMousePos.x <= borderWidth)
                    return HTBOTTOMLEFT;
                else if (clientMousePos.x >= windowRect.right - borderWidth)
                    return HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
                else
                    return HTBOTTOM;
            }
            else if (clientMousePos.y <= borderWidth)
            {
                if (clientMousePos.x <= borderWidth)
                    return HTTOPLEFT;
                else if (clientMousePos.x >= windowRect.right - borderWidth)
                    return HTTOPRIGHT;
                else
                    return HTTOP;
            }
            else if (clientMousePos.x <= borderWidth)
            {
                return HTLEFT;
            }
            else if (clientMousePos.x >= windowRect.right - borderWidth)
            {
                return HTRIGHT;
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    
    return CallWindowProc(original_proc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
void disableTitlebar(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    HWND hWnd = glfwGetWin32Window(window);

    LONG_PTR lStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
    lStyle |= WS_THICKFRAME;
    lStyle &= ~WS_CAPTION;
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);

    RECT windowRect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &windowRect);
    int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
    int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;

    original_proc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC);
    (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(WindowProc));
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE);
}
```